# RapidJSON library getting value without name field

Tags: c++, json

We got json reply similar to following from certain partner's api.

```
[
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName": "Jones" }
]
```

when we tried to parse through rapidjson lib, parse didn't return any error, but we are not sure how to get value from document without the name field on the array. Anyone has any idea to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string s("[ { \"firstName\":\"John\" , \"lastName\":\"Doe\" }, "
              "  { \"firstName\":\"Anna\" , \"lastName\":\"Smith\" }, "
              "  { \"firstName\":\"Peter\" , \"lastName\": \"Jones\" } ]");

rapidjson::Document doc;
doc.Parse<0>(s.c_str());

for (rapidjson::SizeType i = 0; i < doc.Size(); i++)
    printf("\n%u: %s %s", i + 1, doc[i]["firstName"].GetString(), doc[i]["lastName"].GetString());
```